# What's the worst a world can be corrupted at the start?

Tags: terraria

What's the worst a world can be corrupted at the start?

I have a Celebrationmk10 world, that seems to be covered with a lot of Crimson, but I wonder if it's as bad as I think or if just the surface is heavily Crimson.

I don't have enough houses to get the Dryad yet, so I can't check how bad it is, but how bad *could* it be? And it seems it's not that bad. 1% Hallow, 4% Crimson, the surface is just sorta bad? I guess I used some Hallow seeds from another world, or Celebration worlds have some Hallow?

A.k.a, what's the highest percentage of corruption / crimson a world can be when first spawned.

Comment: Yeah, the [wiki](https://terraria.wiki.gg/wiki/Celebrationmk10#Overall) mentions that all floating islands in this seed have hallowed grass, so 1% makes sense since they round it internally. I think the only way to answer your original question would be to look at the decompiled code. I was able to check an older version of the game and didn't find any simple ratio being used as a max limit, so one will probably have to dig into the actual generation algorithm.